# Initialization of object in a class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, default-constructor

```
class CustomerId{
    public:
        CustomerId(int a) : a_(a){
            std::cout << a;
        }
        
    private:
        int a_{0};
};

class Customer {

  public:
    Customer(int a): customer_id_(a){}

  private:
   CustomerId customer_id_;
};
```

I am sorry if this is very stupid, but I am stuck on understanding how object of a class A declared in other class B work.

In this example, we have declared `CustomerId customer_id_` as a member variable in class `Customer`. My assumption was that I would need to create a default constructor for `CustomerId` because the declaration would also create an object. I was taking cues from how we can initialize primitives at the time of declaration such as `a_{0}` in `CustomerId`.

But looks like that is not the case.

Can someone help me understand how objects declared as member variables inside other classes work?

Comment: Because `Customer` defines its own constructors and does not define a default constructor, it is not default-constructible. That means nothing ever needs to default-construct `CustomerId`, which would otherwise result in an error.

Comment: When you declare no constructors at all C++ will create a default constructor for you. When you declare a constructor of your own, C++ will a (implicitly) delete your default constructor. So your class is still constructible but only with the constructor you declared. Note that it is a good practice to make constructors like yours with only ONE argument `explicit` to avoid your class to be implicitly be constructed from an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My assumption was that I would need to create a default constructor for CustomerId because the declaration would also create an object.*

Not really – the *declaration* of a class *does not* create an object of that class (or any embedded members) – that's what the constructor does, when you declare an *object* of the containing class (or otherwise create one).

In your case, the ***only*** constructor for `Customer` properly initializes its `CustomerId` member in the initializer list, with the `customer_id_(a)` call. Take that away, or add a default constructor for `Customer` and you will get an error. For example:

```cpp
class CustomerId {
public:
    CustomerId(int a) : a_(a) {
        std::cout << a;
    }

private:
    int a_{ 0 };
};

class Customer {

public:
    Customer() {}; // Error: 'CustomerId': no appropriate default constructor available
    Customer(int a) : customer_id_(a) {}

private:
    CustomerId customer_id_;
};
```

In the code you have shown, the default constructor for `Customer` is implicitly deleted (because you have defined another one), so there is no way that a `Customer` object can be created without there being an appropriate call to the (non-default) constructor for the embedded `CustomerId` object.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Sorry, one more question - if the default constructor is not defined, when do the fields declared like `int a_{0}` get initialized? Is it even meaningful to do so in such cases?

Comment: @0Nicholas In the absence of any other initializer for the `a_` member, then the one you specified will be used. Same for a class variable - if you add a similar initial value to your `CustomerId`, then that will be used unless the c'tor overrides it.